# How to pick the phonenumer using the ContactPicker and Contact classes in windows phone 8.1 runtime app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

i can able to get the email and display names as well but i couldn't find any property to get the phone number of what i have selected, and my code is below

var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
            contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.PhoneNumber);
            Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();

```
        if (contact != null)
        {

        }
```

Comment: I have used ContactPhone class and its works for me now my code is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string phoneNumber = string.Empty;
            var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
            contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.PhoneNumber);
            Contact contact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();

            if (contact != null)
            {
                foreach (ContactPhone phone in contact.Phones as IList<ContactPhone>)
                {
                    phoneNumber = phone.Number;
                }
            }
```